# Beta distribution and beta binomial distribution

Tags: distributions, beta-binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

What is the difference or relation between beta distribution, beta binomial distribution and binomial distribution?

Comment: There are a number of differences. What application are you looking at? In what context did this question arise? There are too many differences to feasibly list them all, and even then we would be guessing to answer you question. Can you provide us with more information?

Answer (score 6):

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution):

> The beta-binomial distribution is the binomial distribution in which the probability of success at each trial is not fixed but random and follows the beta distribution.

You can read more about the beta distribution [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), the binomial distribution [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), and the beta binomial distribution [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution)